# any android open source project can send utf-8 SMS from API?

Tags: android

I want to send SMS to a large number of my customers, is there any existing open source project for android can do it? I want to SDK/API to send, not from GUI, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

encode your message before sending `CharsetEncoder` will do the job.

Comment: any api & example to send sms?